# ANTLR4 parsing different versions of the string

Tags: antlr, antlr4

There are different forms of incoming string, which begins with a double quote and ends with it too. Inside the quotation marks there may be different strings that need to be assigned to a certain type.
Examples:

1. "Simple text"
2. "Field20"
3. ">=20"
4. ">20<=10"
5. "20"
   These strings are parsed through the mode

Lexer.g4

```
...
WQ: '"' -> pushMode(IN_STRING) ;
DIGIT: [0-9]+ ;
...
mode IN_STRING;
DQUOTE_IN_STRING: '"' -> type(WQ), popMode ;
BEGIN_EXPR: [<=>]+ -> pushMode(EXP) ;
STRING: ~["]+;

mode EXP;
DQUOTE_IN_EXP: '"' -> type(WQ), mode(DEFAULT_MODE) ;
COMPARE_EXPR: [<=>]+ ;
EXPESSION: DIGIT+ ;
...
```

However, it does not go into EXP mode when parsing the token stream.
The reason is the STRING expression. But how to describe an expression so that it doesn't include sequences that start with comparison characters I can't figure out. Help with advice, maybe you can suggest another way to parse the given examples?

Comment: Antlr lexers always match the longest string regardless of order. That's why STRING is preferred over BEGIN_EXPR. You have to create a lexer rule that contains everything except `"`, but also `<`, `>`, `=`, for STRING. Here's where Antlr is not very nice: you have to explicitly list all possible characters in your input language character set. Yeah, there's no `-`-operator. E.g., `STRING: [0-9a-zA-Z.$]+` etc.

Comment: @kaby76 Thank you for your comment, I'm trying different options